# How do I have my Discord.JS bot respond to me in DMs

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Basically if I send the bot `.hello` (the prefix is `.`), I would have the bot respond with "hello" or something of that sort.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

```
if(message.content.startsWith('.hello') && message.channel.type === 'dm') message.reply('hello')
```

Really basic, but does your job.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the [author](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=author) of the message then create a [DMChannel](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=createDM) (notice that it is a promise) than you can just use the regular [send](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/DMChannel?scrollTo=send) method.